# Making sense of disparity values after applying `StereoSGBM` from OpenCV

Tags: stereo-vision, opencv

I just started with Kitty Stereo Dataset (2015). The first thing I did was compute the disparity using the [`stereoSGBM`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d85/classcv_1_1StereoSGBM.html) class. And here is the **rectified input images** and the disparity output from the application of `stereoSGBM`:
[image]

[image]

As the colorbar indicates, the raw disparity values in the disparity image go from `0 -> 1000`. I didn't expect such high values of disparity. **How do I interpret these disparity values?**

Further, to fill holes in the disparity map, I used `cv.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter` object. And I get the filtered disparity:

[image]

The filtered disparity again has high values in range of ~1000. **How to make sense of these disparity values? How do I obtain the correct disparity values (in pixels) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the documentation of `StereoSGBM` I found the following explaination [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d6e/classcv_1_1StereoMatcher.html#a03f7087df1b2c618462eb98898841345).

[image]

It says: Some algorithms, like StereoBM or StereoSGBM compute 16-bit fixed point disparity map (where each disparity value has 4 fractional bits).

So, I simply applied 4 right shifts to drop the fractional part using `numpy.right_shift()` and I get some sensible disparity values.
[image]

Note that ideally, one should not throw away the 4 fractional bits.

Comment: I was going to ask what the *units* were on that disparity, but glad you found the answer! You can also accept your own answer so other users can find solutions in the future :D

Comment: That's great, thanks for the reply... it would be great to know WHY this output format was chosen!!

Comment: @EdwardAndo  The documentation does not tell much, but I think this particular format is memory efficient and disparity computation results from block matching do not produce very fine disparity changes (4 bits will capture only about 16 fractional levels).